# any functions available in java or related libraries for generating random data in normal distribution

Tags: statistics

i want to generate normally distributed random data matrices. Are there any java or related functions available for implementing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is built into the standard libraries.

Use `Random.nextGaussian()` [defined here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()).

This returns a floating-point number for a normal distribution with mean `0.0` and standard deviation `1.0`.

If you need a random number from a distribution of mean `m` and standard deviation `s`, use this expression:

```
( Random.nextGaussian() * s ) + m
```

Comment: In some of the runs of the program i got no.s above 1.0 
when m =0;  s =1;
Any idea why this may happen?
I use eclipse IDE for running the program.

Comment: About 82% of the values should be less than 1.0.  If you only generated a few numbers, your result is expected.

Comment: I used this approach first, but when I then tested the generated distribution, I found out that it often deviates a bit from the expected values. For those who experience something similar, maybe it might be a good idea to look at cern.jet.random.engine.DRand and cern.jet.random.Normal.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Uncommons Maths](https://uncommons-maths.dev.java.net/) - it should be able to help.

Comment: i got a look at uncommon math
it is not particularly concerned with java.
i was looking for a module or function for producing uniformly distributed no.s.